# Applications of identity theorem to physics

Tags: complex-analysis, soft-question, physics, applications, analyticity

Holomorphic functions have the property that they can be uniquely analytically continued to (almost) the entire complex plane. So, just by knowing how the function behaves at a teenie-weenie open disc in $\mathbb{C}$, the behavior at a much larger scale is uniquely defined.

Does this extraordinarily beautiful property have any direct applications in physics? For example, you know how some kind of field looks in a tiny area and you can somehow assume it is described by a holomorphic function and by analytic continuation you "extrapolate" the field to a much bigger domain.

EDIT: I cross-posted this on [physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/89072/applications-of-identity-theorem-to-physics), it might fit better there.

Comment: Well, physicists use this by evaluating their formulas plugging in imaginary time, or imaginary energy, or something.  And expecting to get  a useful answer.  One case I saw... the formula for the number of 2-element subsets of a set with $n$ elements is $n(n-1)/2$.  But then this was to be used by plugging in a value $n$ with $0<n<1$.  No hint that it may be a questionable thing to do.

Comment: @GEdgar What does it even mean to have a set with a fractional number of elements?

Comment: It doesn't mean anything!  Why do you ask?  Where did you see a "fractional number of elements"?  If you are referring to "n(n-1)/2", for any n, either n is even or n-1 is even.  In either case, n(n-1) is even so n(n-1)/2 is always a non-negative integer.